# How to make a button to refesh a div for showing information

Tags: php, jquery, html

Well, first, I have to sorry about my English. But here is my problem, hope you guy can help me. Thanks alot.

I have a php web page about Harry Potter fansite. And this page seem like this:

div1 on the left: the map with some images (these images are button or href link).
div2 on the right: show information of the images.

For example:
- In div1, I have a Harry image and a Voldemort image. I want when I press into Harry Image, div2 will show info like: "Name: Harry, Age: 11...". Something like that.

I don't want to refresh all the web too much.

Oh, and about my code:
I have another php web called Library.php where I wrote all information already.
ex: $name[1] = "Harry Potter"; $age[1] = "11"; $name[2] = "Voldemort"...;
and picture in div1 take value from a php called Map.php where I wrote all information about images on div1. ex: $map[1] = "harrypic"...

So in div1 code, I just need to call `echo "<img src= '{$map[1]}.jpg'>"`.

So, how can I make those image become button, which when I press it, the div2 will show info for me? Thank you very much.

my Image code:

```
echo "<img style='position:absolute; TOP:{$Map[$i]['y']}px; LEFT:{$Map[$i]['x']}px;' src='images/button{$button}.gif' title='{$Map[$i]['name']}'>";
```

and div2:... don't know how yet.

---

Update:
I use a css, like that:

```
  <?php
echo "<html><head>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />";
echo "<title>HPVOF - Con đường tơ lụa</title>";
include('configMap.php');
echo "<title>Spoiler HTML code</title>
        <style type='text/css'>
        body,input
            {
            color:#51270b;
            }
        .spoiler
            {
            padding:3px;
            }
        .spoiler .inner
            {
            padding:3px;margin:3px;
            }
        label[for] {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        input[name=radio] {
            display: none;
        }
        #description p {
            display: none;
        }";

        for($i=1; $i <= $MapSoluong; $i ++)  //$MapSoluong is number of pictures.
        {
            echo " #rd{$i}:checked ~ #description .info{$i} {
                display: block;
                } 
                ";
        }

echo "</style>";
echo "</head>";

$offline = false;
if($offline != "true")
{

    $Tempmapimages = $_POST["mapimages"];   
    if($Tempmapimages > 0) $mapimages = $Tempmapimages;
    else 
    {
        $mapimages = 1;
    }

    $mapvalue2 = $mapimages + 1;
    $mapvalue1 = $mapimages - 1;    

    echo "<body style='background-color:#000000;'>";
    echo "<div style='width:1700px;'>";
    echo "<div style='width:1250px; height:900px; float: left; background-image:url(images/bg{$mapimages}.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;color: #ffffff'>";

    if($mapimages > 1)
    {
        echo "<form action='map.php' method='post'>                 
                    <input type='hidden' name='mapimages' value='{$mapvalue1}' />                   
                    <span style='position: absolute; top: 47px; left: 1100px; color: #51270b'><input type='submit' value=' < '> </span>
                    </form>";
    }           
    if($mapimages < 2) 
    {
        echo "<form action='map.php' method='post'>                 
                    <input type='hidden' name='mapimages' value='{$mapvalue2}' />                   
                    <span style='position: absolute; top: 47px; left: 1100px; color: #51270b'><input type='submit' value=' > '> </span>
                    </form>";
    }

    echo "<span style='position: absolute; top: 53px; left: 300px; color: #51270b'><strong>Bản đồ số {$mapimages} /2</strong> </span>"; 

    for($i=1; $i <= $MapSoluong; $i ++)
    {
        echo " <input type='radio' id='rd{$i}' name='radio' /> 
            ";  
    }

    if($mapimages == 1)
    {           
        for($i=1; $i <= $MapSoluong; $i ++)  //$MapSoluong is number of pictures.
        {           
            if($i == 1) $button = 3;
            else $button = 1;
            echo "<label for='rd{$i}'>
                <img style='position:absolute; TOP:{$Map[$i]['y']}px; LEFT:{$Map[$i]['x']}px;' src='images/button{$button}.gif' title='{$Map[$i]['name']}'>
                </label> 
                ";
        }

    }//======================
    echo "</div>";

    //-------------------- thong tin
    echo "<div id='description'; style='width:400px; float: left; color: #ffffff'>";
    echo "<br/>";
    for($i=1; $i <= $MapSoluong; $i ++)  //$MapSoluong is number of pictures.
    {
        echo "<p class='info{$i}'>Harry poter {$i} zzzz</p>";
    }               
    echo "</div>";
    //-------------------------------------------------
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</body></html>";
}
else 
{
    echo "<body style='background-color:#a18e73; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size: 18px;'>";
    echo "<center><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/> Chỉ học viên chính thức mới được phép tham gia nơi này! </center>";
    echo "</body></html>";
}

?>
```

But it not work

Comment: If you only need it for styling purpose, you could just use CSS for that using a checkbox/radio and label, depending your HTML markup  https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

Comment: ah, a very good trick!

Comment: You didn't posted any relevant HTML markup, so i cannot show you anything. If you want example, check link in my previous comment and read it

Comment: but how to combine Image with those thing. Help me please. I'm lack of coding :3

Comment: @Albus Dumble Trôn do you still want help to implement the code offered?

Answer (score 0):

If for styling purpose only, you can just use CSS and use any relevant HTML markup. See more info [there](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/).

Here a simple example. But you could animate it or whatever CSS support as transition/animation.

```css
label[for] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[name=radio] {
    display: none;
}
#description p {
    display: none;
}
#rd1:checked ~ #description .harry {
    display: block;
}
#rd2:checked ~ #description .voldemort {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="rd1" name="radio" />
<input type="radio" id="rd2" name="radio" />
<label for="rd1">
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
</label>
<label for="rd2">
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
</label>
<div id="description">
    <p class="harry">Harry poter blablabla...</p>
    <p class="voldemort">Other guy i don't care too blablabla...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir, please check my update code edit with yours. But somehow it isn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you want something to do with AJAX. If you want a user to click on the image, then the DIV starts loading to fetch relevant information from the server without having to reload the whole page, [AJAX](http://www.asp.net/ajax) is your best option. However, if you want it instantly without having to load, you could load the data for the DIV then store in a JavaScript variable. You could do that like so:

echo "<script>var_name=".$php_var."</script>";

That should work for you. You could as well load the data into a hidden DIV where you'd fetch it when a the images with a certain ID is clicled. You set that like  the later call it in JavaScript using that ID.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `innerHTML`?  Possible suggestion for getting all of the images with their associated information out into a div using a loop.

```
<div>

<?php include("Library.php"); 
      include("Map.php"); //include the path if not local to script to get your data pages        
?>

<?php $c = count( $map ); ?>
<?php while ( $i < $c ){ ?>
<img src="<?php echo $map[$i]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name[$i]; ?>" title="<?php echo $name[$i]; ?>" onClick="document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = <?php echo "'<p>Name: " . $name[$i] . '<br />Age: ' . $age[$i] . '<br />Description: ' . $description[$i] . "</p>'"; ?>" />
<?php $i++;
} ?>

</div>

<div id="description">
</div>
```

Basic demonstration HTML

```
<img src="voldemort.jpg" alt="Voldemort" title="Voldemort" onClick="document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = '<p>Voldemort description</p>'" />
```

Comment: Did this work? You should have been able to drop it all inside a div with a change to the variable names to match what you have. Happy to go further with it if you wish.

Answer (score -1):

You need javascript and jquery for this, more on:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

Look at this working example, open with browser and click on div, div2 will be shown:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.div').click(function(){
            $('.div2').show();
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="div">div</div>
<div class="div2" style="display: none;">div2</div>
```

Comment: that what I know, but... how :|